# SQL query to get the average time spent by user on page

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-query-store

Here is a sample table that I am using,

```
User_id           timestamp            action
1            2020-10-01 09:00:00    Opened page
1            2020-10-01 09:10:00    Closed page
2            2020-10-02 04:00:00    Signed up
3            2020-10-02 06:00:00    Opened page
3            2020-10-03 11:00:00    Made a booking
3            2020-10-03 09:30:00    Closed page
```

need to write a SQL query to find the average time spent by a user on the page.

The expected answer is just a number which represents the average time spent by an average user on the page.

Comment: Please explain how that is calculated.

Comment: Specify the expected result too.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: @jarlh, the expected answer is just a number which represents the average time spent by an average user on the page.

Comment: That's _describing_ the result. But since it's far from clear what you want, I'd still recommend you to specify the expected result.

Comment: @jarlh, sum(time spent by each user on the page) / (total number of users)

please let me know if you need some other clarity too. :)

Comment: This link has something very similar: https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/how-to-use-values-from-previous-or-next-rows-in-a-query-in-sql-server/ Ok, it is SQLSever and not MySQL, but it shows the complexities. Anything can be resolved in SQL, but it can be highly complex. I ususally pull things aparat and use several steps - but for that you need server side code with embedded SQL.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem to do averaging in any language.  All I think you need to do is `select DATE_DIFF(field1, field2)`, and then sum and divide this.  Have you tried that?

Comment: DATE_DIFF(field1, field2) would be really easy but that requires the two fields to be in the same row ...

Comment: @HoldOffHunger, I am having issue in defining the length of a single session in SQL, need to determine the duration between a consecutive "opened page" and "closed page" action and add all those durations to determine the time spent by a user, that's where I am facing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t use SQL to calculate how much time a user spends on different pages of your UI application. You will need to implement this logic on your UI whenever there is an event such as when the user navigates to another page or a button click etc. You capture the timestamps you need on the UI and then make a database call through an SP call or Query through your server side code (such as .Net, Java or Node.js).

Once you have captured the data from the UI you will be able to implement any kind of logic on that data through an SP or a function or something like that in using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [**`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff), and set its argument to `SECOND`, you can get back the difference of two datetime fields in a record in a manner that can be summed and divided.  Documentation:

> Returns datetime_expr2 − datetime_expr1, where datetime_expr1 and datetime_expr2 are date or datetime expressions.

Then use [**`SUM()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_sum) to sum up these values, and divide by the results of [**`COUNT()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count).  Documentation:

> ***`SUM()`***: Returns the sum of expr. If the return set has no rows, SUM() returns NULL.
> ***`COUNT()`***: Returns a count of the number of non-NULL values of expr in the rows retrieved by a SELECT statement.

Your code will then basically look like this.  You may need to make some adjustments based on your database setup.

```
SELECT
    SUM(
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, OrigDateTime, LastDateTime)
    ) / (select COUNT(id) FROM yourTable)
    AS average
FROM yourTable;
```

This, of course, follows our standard formula for calculating an average:

> `sum(differences) / count(differences)`

Comment: But both "OrigDateTime" and "LastDateTime" are in the same column i.e. timestamp column

Comment: Right, as I stated, *"You may need to make some adjustments based on your database setup."*  You may need to reorganize your db just to make this as easy as I describe above.  Otherwise, you may have to do tons of `JOIN`s.  I have no idea what your database structure is, you didn't provide it.  I'm just trying to provide a general solution to the given problem -- so someone who did know their db structure could solve their own problem.